# JQuery mobile causes errors after including in PhoneGap/Cordova app

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am trying to use jquery mobile in my `Phonegap/Cordova` app, but unfortunately I have been trying to include it without any success.
When I include `jquery mobile` in my main `index.html` like this

```
<!--JQuery Mobile-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

It causes different errors, first of all in `JQuery` file

```
I/chromium( 3832): [INFO:CONSOLE(3)] "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'apply'", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js (3)
```

And in some other modules

```
"Uncaught NotFoundError: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist.", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/please-wait.min.js (264)
```

I don't know what is wrong, why does `JQuery Mobile` cause such error ? Please help to solve this problem

Comment: could be element/Attribute name conflict. BTW try jQuery 2.1, jQm has some issues with jQ2.2

Comment: @ArpitVasani it seems that the problem is with `JQuery mobile` not with `JQuery` because after including it everything crashes

Comment: @ketazafor It may not be an issue with jQ2.2 as this combo works fine for me. Could be a javascript coding issue. Could you post the code?